# Passing time as argument in django url

Tags: django

in my view I have an argument of time to be passed but how do i pass it through a django url

my view is

```
def create_event(check):
TimeSlots.objects.create(start=check)
return HttpResponseRedirect("index.html")
```

and i tried a url

```
url(r'^new/(?P<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})/$', views.create_event, name='check'),
```

I called it as

```
<a href="{% url 'check' 08:30:00 %}">click</a>
```

but it doesnt work and gives error 
Could not parse the remainder: ':30:00' from '08:30:00'

Comment: Include it as a *string*.

Comment: now it gives error create_event() got an unexpected keyword argument 'time'

Comment: you forgot the `request` parameter, an named the parameter `check` instead of `time`. See answer.

Comment: oh now i get it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you pass `08:30:30` as a "raw expression". But Django templates fail to understand what you do with that colon.

You need to pass the parameter as a string, like:

```
<a href="{% url 'check' time='08:30:00' %}">click</a>
<!--                         ^ quote  ^  -->
```

Since your URL contains a `time` parameter, you need to handle it in the view:

```
def create_event(request, time):
    TimeSlots.objects.create(start=time)
    return HttpResponseRedirect("index.html")
```

Note that this view makes changes to the entities, and therefore this normally should be handled by a POST request. GET requests are normally not supposed to make (significant) changes.